# thread died in the pthread_mutex_lock with SIGILL signal

Tags: c, pthreads, mips, uclinux

I'm developing an project on an embedded linux OS(uclinux, mips CPU), It crashed occasionally. 
When I try to check coredump with gdb, I can see that it received a SIGILL signal.

Sometime I can see the backtrace, which showed it died in pthread_mutex_lock. but most time, backtrace is not valid.

A valid backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  <signal handler called>
#1  0x2ab87fd8 in sigsuspend () from /lib/libc.so.0
#2  0x2aade80c in __pthread_wait_for_restart_signal () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x2aadc7ac in __pthread_alt_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x2aad81a4 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x0042fde8 in aos_mutex_lock (mutex=0x66bea8) at ../../source/ssp/os/sys/linux/aos_lock_linux.c:184
```

invalid backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00690430 in ?? ()
#1  0x00690430 in ?? ()
```

I used pthread_attr_setstackaddr to initial a stack for each thread, so that I can see its call frame through checking its stack. Also, I found it died in pthread_mutex_lock.

I used a wrapper for lock and unlock like

```
struct aos_mutex_t
{
    pthread_mutex_t     mutex;
    S8                  obj_name[AOS_MAX_OBJ_NAME];
    S32                 lFlag;
};
S32 aos_mutex_lock(AOS_MUTEX_T *mutex)
{
    S32 status;

    AOS_ASSERT_RETURN(mutex, AOS_EINVAL);

    mutex->lFlag++;
    status = pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex->mutex );

    if (status == 0)
    {
        return AOS_SUCC;
    }
    else
    {
        return AOS_RETURN_OS_ERROR(status);
    }
}

/*
 * aos_mutex_unlock()
 */
S32 aos_mutex_unlock(AOS_MUTEX_T *mutex)
{
    S32 status;


    AOS_ASSERT_RETURN(mutex, AOS_EINVAL);

    status = pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex->mutex );
    mutex->lFlag--;
    if (status == 0)
        return AOS_SUCC;
    else
    {
        return AOS_RETURN_OS_ERROR(status);
    }

}
```

All of these mutex is initiated before using them.

I tried gdb to run the program, it didn't die.

I wrote a simple program, 11 threads do nothing bug just lock and unlock in a dead loop. It didn't die.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: I've encountered almost the exact same problem on certain demo boards, but before going forward, can you dump your code to pastebin or something similar? Usually this is due to a faulty thread initialization sequence.

Comment: All the threads are created and ran. Could it be due to faulty thread initialization sequence.